# Sql server to PHP (api vs library)

Tags: php, .net, api, mysql, sql-server

Our agency is currently using and maintaining the CMS we have developed in .net MVC on SQL server.

Since the cms is highly optimized and uses various cache tables to run very fast even with thousand of pages we want to keep it the same and use it for some php websites we will do in the next months.

In this condition you would consider making a API on the cms backend or create a 
php library that directly access the sql server to obtain better performance?

Comment: There isn't enough specific information here to make your question answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create API to be used from the PHP websites. The CMS caches are managed by the .NET application, and you don't won't to rewrite how to manage them again in PHP.

It'd be lot easier to export the same .net Model with API rather than creating another one.

You also will get a cleaner separation between your Model and Controller in on the PHP side because the API will practically be the Model.